# PHP Mailer is sending Duplicated Email (two emails at once)

Tags: php, mailer

PHP mailer is sending two emails at once i tried to send it without loop just a single email but it was the same result

I found this here on stackoverflow  but not changing anything

`$mail->SingleTo = true;`

So  what can i do for this how can i send only one email per recipient ?

Here is my custom Mailer class

```
class Mailer
{
    public static function sendMail($subject, $msgWithHtml, $msgNotHtml, array $recipients, array $attachmentPath = null )
    {
        $mail = new \PHPMailer;

        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'mail.lotfio-lakehal.com';                // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'noreplay@lotfio-lakehal.com';      // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '------------';                     // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('noreplay@lotfio-lakehal.com');

        foreach($recipients as $email) 
        { 
            $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient  // Name is optional
        }

        $mail->SingleTo = true; //will send mail to each email address individually

        $mail->addReplyTo('contact@lotfio-lakehal.com', 'Information');

        if($attachmentPath){
            foreach($attachmentPath as $file) 
            { 
                $mail->addAttachment($file);
            }
        }


        $mail->isHTML(true);                 // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $msgWithHtml;
        $mail->AltBody = $msgNotHtml;

        return $mail->send();
    }
}
```

and here is how iam calling this method

```
use fordev\app\helpers\Mailer;

   Mailer::sendMail('Email test from mailer', '<div></div>', 'qdqsdq dqsdqsdqsd', ['lotfiolakehal@gmail.com','contact@lotfio-lakehal.com']);
```

Comment: how are you calling the above ?

Comment: @nogad  take a look to the code it's updated now :)

Comment: It is sending for each address two emails?

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel yep ossama

Comment: you must be calling it twice.

Comment: @nogad !!! Why twice i just want to send a single email !

Comment: He didn't tell you to call it twice dude chill. "you must be calling it twice", he is just assuming you are calling it twice.

Comment: @nogad sorry for mis understanding :) im just calling it once

Comment: you say that .. but the results say something else. your getting 4 emails 2 for each address right? how about if only one address, neither of those addresses are alises?

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel the method returns Bool then i can chek if sent or not

Comment: Yeah that was a shot in the dark, took down the answer, my bad.

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel no worries we are learning from each other :)

Comment: Upload the whole php file where you are making the calls, and comment the link.

Answer (score 1):

### SingleTo with The SMTP Transport

The SingleTo is only supported in "mail" and "sendmail" transports, not in "SMTP".

Since you use the "SMTP" transport, The SingleTo won't work. The authors of the PHPMailer class should have thrown an exception to exclude cases like that when when the SingleTo is not actually honored. If you use the SMTP transport, just loop the send for each address one-by-one (just call $mail->addAddress one time to pass just one address for each instance of the PHPMailer class), and don't touch the SingleTo property value, keep it default (false).

### Plans on SingleTo in Future Versions of The PHPMailer

SingleTo is planned to be deprecated in the release of PHPMailer 6.0, and removed in 7.0. The authors of PHPMailer expalained that it's better to control sending to multiple recipients at a higher level:

> PHPMailer isn't a mailing list sender.

Source: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1042

> Use of the PHP mail() function needs to be discouraged because it's extremely difficult to use safely; SMTP is faster, safer, and gives more control and feedback."

### Your Question

The question was "So what can i do for this how can i send only one email per recipient?"

Just modify the arguments of the sendMail and change it from "array $recipients" to just a single $recipient, so it will the this:

```
public static function sendMail($subject, $msgWithHtml, $msgNotHtml, $recipient, array $attachmentPath = null )
```

And replace the following code

```
    foreach($recipients as $email)
    {
        $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient  // Name is optional
    }
```

to

```
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);
```

If you cannot modify the declaration of the sendMail function since it's alreay used by other code, keep it, but move all its code to another function:

```
public static function sendMailSingleRecipient($subject, $msgWithHtml, $msgNotHtml, $recipient, array $attachmentPath = null )
```

so the code of the function sendMail will be like that:

```
    foreach($recipients as $email)
    {
        self::sendMailSingleRecipient($subject, $msgWithHtml, $msgNotHtml, $email, $attachmentPath)
    }
```

The whole code will be the following:

```
class Mailer
{
    public static function sendMailSingleRecipient($subject, $msgWithHtml, $msgNotHtml, $recipient, array $attachmentPath = null )
    {
        $mail = new \PHPMailer;

        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'mail.lotfio-lakehal.com';                // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'noreplay@lotfio-lakehal.com';      // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = '------------';                     // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('noreplay@lotfio-lakehal.com');

        $mail->addAddress($recipient);     // Add a recipient  // Name is optional

        $mail->addReplyTo('contact@lotfio-lakehal.com', 'Information');

        if($attachmentPath){
            foreach($attachmentPath as $file)
            {
                $mail->addAttachment($file);
            }
        }


        $mail->isHTML(true);                 // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $msgWithHtml;
        $mail->AltBody = $msgNotHtml;

        return $mail->send();
    }

    public static function sendMail($subject, $msgWithHtml, $msgNotHtml, array $recipients, array $attachmentPath = null )
    {
        foreach($recipients as $email)
        {
            self::sendMailSingleRecipient($subject, $msgWithHtml, $msgNotHtml, $email, $attachmentPath)
        }
    }

}
```

If you still don't like that the sendMail function loops for each of the addresses, but you need to use the smtp transport (not sendmail and not mail) don't use the \PHPMailer class from that third-party library hosted at GitHub and implement the smtp transport by yourself. You will anyway have to send each message separately to the SMTP server over the TCP/IP connection, but each message will have only one "To:" recipient and the messages would not duplicate.

### PHP Log

If you suspect that the existing code is still but the function is called twice, just add logging capabilities to your code and check how many times it has been called. If you can see php error log, just add the error_log() to the beginning of the function, e.g.

```
error_log(print_r($recipients, true));
```

or

```
error_log(implode(',', $recipients));
```

So you will see from the log how many times the function have been actually called. Just don't forget to remove the error_log line from your code. If you don't have access to the error log file, use file_put_contents:

```
file_put_contents($filepath, implode(',', $recipients).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Before calling it, set $filepath to the path name of the file to which you have access.

Comment: @nogad - Why don't you think this is not an answer to the question? Question was: "So what can i do for this how can i send only one email per recipient?". The answer was: "If you use the SMTP transport, just loop the send for each address one-by-one.", and there were given an alternative choices above: use "mail" and "sendmail" transports, not in "SMTP". If you still think that this was not an answer to the question "So what can i do for this how can i send only one email per recipient?" - I have updated the answer.

Comment: his code should already be only sending one email, if 2 are being sent it has noting to do wit the code preovided

Comment: @MaximMasiutin on my question i said that i did try to send without for loop exactly like you answered but the same thing

Comment: @ForDev - you have used both SingleTo and SMTP, which is not allowed. Just remove the SingleTo if you are using SMTP. I still see both SingleTo and SMTP in your code.

Comment: @nogad - I do not agree that the code is OK as soon as there are SingleTo set to true and the transport is SMTP. First, we have removed wither SingleTo or SMTP and then check again, even if it is already sending mails properly, only one email.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin i already tried without SingleTo and keeps getting the same thing that was the only solution i found on stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264693/phpmailer-5-1-sends-duplicatie-mails-when-adding-more-than-1-receiver

Comment: @ForDev since you wrote that you "did try to send without for loop exactly like you answered but the same thing", look what have written - the code should already send just one email. Since he suspects that your code is called twice, add loging capabilities to it and let us know how many time it is called. I have updated my reply about the logging.

Comment: @nogad - your comment about the code being called twice - and it is the cause of duplicates (not the sending procedure) is very reasonable. See my comment above.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin here is the whole project https://github.com/lotfio-lakehal/fordev with a email setup for testing  so if you want to try it just clone it and run composer and see

Comment: @ForDev - thank you for sharing the link to the project github.com/lotfio-lakehal/fordev  - I cannot check the project at the moment. Just tried to be helpful with the tips about the SingleTo+SMTP and about logging. I'm using logging myself very much in PHP. I don't have debuggers or complex tools - just simple write to file or to the error log. If my tips didn't help - I'm sorry for that. Just tried to be little bit helpful and add insight that no one have given.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin thaks we really appreciate it

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. This happens if you call `$mail->Send()` twice.

Delete the `send` function of your PHPmailer config file, and add an `if` statement at the end of your instruction:

```
include ("../PHPMailer/sendEmail.php");

if($mail->Send()) {
    echo "ok";

} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```